# Cannot resolve domain name from inside my network

Tags: networking, router, dns

So I have a web server running on a computer in my local network, port 5000. It works great from everywhere except within my network, for some reason it can't seem to figure it out. Whats annoying, is that it used to work, I changed nothing (that I can remember) and it suddenly stopped working. I have a pihole running on my network which I suspect is the ultimate source of the issue. I have tried enabling the DHCP server on my pihole, and turning off the one on my router, but all that resulted in was needing to append the port number to access the site from outside the network, and not needing to do so in order to access it from inside my network.

The domain name resolves to my public IP address, so I have port 80 and 443 forwarded to port 5000 on the computer in question. I would just enter the local ip and port to use it if I could, however the site is secured with OAuth, so the request needs to come from the domain itself. Ive been bashing my head against the wall over this for a bit now, Im not sure what else to try. I can ping the domain from inside my network with no problem, so it has to be some issue with the DNS resolution right?

There is the added complication that my network is double NAT'ed, because google fiber routers don't support fully bridged mode. I don't think that is the source of the issue but it seems worth mentioning.

Comment: Are you trying to access your webserver through a browser? What's the error message? Please be more specific especially on your tests (e.g. what exactly did you ping? Domain name? IP?)

Comment: The error message is ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT when I try to visit the domain in browser. I can ping the domain without any problem, both from within and outside of my network. So I guess the DNS resolution is fine, must be a problem with the redirect?

Comment: There is no way to say for sure where the problem comes from at the moment, too little information.